# Error "Array to string conversion" when use Authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

I used Auth::Guard authentication but got an error converting, here's my code in the controller file:

```
const ALL_GUARD = ['admin'];

public function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}

function login(Request $request) 
{
  $dataLogin = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
    // dd($dataLogin);
    // error here
    foreach (self::ALL_GUARD as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($dataLogin)) {
          return redirect('/'.$guard.'/home');
        }
    }
  // }
  return redirect('/login');
}

public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

and Model file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class UserModel extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';
    protected $table = ['users','post'];
    protected $fillable = ['name','email','password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];

}
```

Error:

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Array to string conversion
```

What did I do wrong? It was faulty somewhere, please help me! Thank you!

Comment: because a Model is specific to a single table, you have `$table` set as an array for some reason ... where in the documentation did you see that variable being set as an array? also you should provide more information about errors, such as the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should be one table name in model. please remove array and make it as string, or you can check Laravel Model documentation for more clarification.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class UserModel extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';
    protected $table = 'users'; //change this variable type
    protected $fillable = ['name','email','password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];

}
```

or please provide proper error description.